# Spring Security: Purpose of .oauth2Client(withDefaults()); in HttpSecurity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

This is from the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#oauth2Client(org.springframework.security.config.Customizer))

> public HttpSecurity
> oauth2Client​(Customizer<OAuth2ClientConfigurer>
> oauth2ClientCustomizer) throws java.lang.Exception
>
> Configures OAuth 2.0 Client support.
>
> Example Configuration
>
> The following example demonstrates how to enable OAuth 2.0 Client
> support for all endpoints.
>
> ```
>  @Configuration
>  @EnableWebSecurity
>  public class OAuth2ClientSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>         @Override
>         protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>                 http
>                         .authorizeRequests((authorizeRequests) ->
>                                 authorizeRequests
>                                         .anyRequest().authenticated()
>                         )
>                         .oauth2Client(withDefaults());
>         }
>  }
> ```
>
> Parameters: auth2ClientCustomizer - the Customizer to provide more
> options for the OAuth2ClientConfigurer
>
> Returns:  the HttpSecurity for further customizations

The thing I understood is any requests coming to this server should be authenticated.

How does
`.oauth2Client(withDefaults());` help in this case?

If I'm not wrong, an oAuth2 client is the one sending the requet, what can we actually configure about this? The documentation doesnt really explain much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The http instance of HttpSecurity is a "bean settings server/application side".

Its method **oauth2Client** is not related to client configurations, but how and where the server/application should handle them.

Example:

- Which clients have been authorized
- Where to store authorized clients
- How to authorize clients
- How to remove an old authorized client

Answer (score 1):

I think [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html#oauth2login-completely-override-autoconfiguration) , you can find more details about oauth2Client defaults .

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ClientSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .oauth2Client(oauth2Client ->
                oauth2Client
                    .clientRegistrationRepository(this.clientRegistrationRepository())
                    .authorizedClientRepository(this.authorizedClientRepository())
                    .authorizedClientService(this.authorizedClientService())
                    .authorizationCodeGrant(authorizationCodeGrant ->
                        authorizationCodeGrant
                            .authorizationRequestRepository(this.authorizationRequestRepository())
                            .authorizationRequestResolver(this.authorizationRequestResolver())
                            .accessTokenResponseClient(this.accessTokenResponseClient())
                    )
            );
    }
}
```